# The emulator wont display my app

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I followed the instructions on setting up the emulator for my React_Native app , I downloaded the android studio and set my virtual device, I opened a project using shell and react-native init command with my project name in my visual studio,then in my shell I run the react-native run-android command . The emulator itself works but either displays an empty screen or shows an error 500 related to my previous test application even though I am choosing a completely diferent project in my Android studio. What can be the issue?